# "I wasn't answering the phone because I had fallen asleep."

Tags: past-perfect

Is it possible to say:

> I wasn't answering the phone because I had fallen asleep.

My teacher said that it's not even possible to exist and to say that in English, but I'm not sure about her opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly grammatical, and reasonably natural. It suggests that there were several phone calls that I didn't answer (if it was one particular call, *I didn't answer the phone* would be more normal - though the given example is still possible).

As is often the case with aspects in English (progressive, perfect, etc.) the choice of form is not entirely constrained by the objective events, but partly in the free choice of the speaker, in how they are choosing to refer to the temporal relations among the events they are talking about.

*I wasn't answering the phone* says that the speaker is choosing to regard "not answering the phone" as a continuing state - which is why I say that it suggests that there were several phone calls; but that is only one possible reason why they might choose that form.